# How to store a custom theme and update it on other installations

Tags: plugins, themes

I have developed a custom (private) theme, I plan to use on multiple installations. I would like to have the theme installed on installation (A) and whenever there is a change made to it on (A), update it on installations (B), (C),... by simply "updating" it inside the dashboard (not uploading the updated version).

Sorry, I have no idea how to do that and maybe I asked Google the wrong questions, but I have not found a solution there either?

And the same for plugins? Where must plugins be stored so that updates are recognized wherever the plugins are installed. Thanks for your patience.

Vlo

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is the WP theme directory and the WP plugin directory respectively, but if you want to keep them private this may not be an option.

https://github.com/afragen/github-updater is a good alternative, you can configure it with a private key to update your own themes/plugins from a github repo.

If that's not what you're after then you'll have to look at hosting the theme files and using your own update scripts, which is a fair bit more complex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But how is that done for paid themes? Those aren't hosted in the WP Theme Directory or are they?